# Ajax call for each item in a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following scenario where I need to make an ajax request to an endpoint for each item in the array while i map over it and display it on screen.

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "test"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "test2"
    }
]
```

In my render() method:

render() {

```
    return (
        items.map((item) => {
            <div>{item.name}</div>

            // function that returns a promise
            // the endpoint requires the item's id
            this.apiCall(item.id).then((returnedValue) => {
                return <div>{returnedValue}</div>
            });
        })
    );
}
```

But running it throws this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Minified React error #31; Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).`

Comment: You need to return your JSX synchronously from the render method, so you are better of getting your API data in `componentDidMount` and setting it in the component state when the requests are done.

Comment: @Tholle I tried your method but since i'm mapping over `items` and setting to state, state always gets set to the last item's call.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Promise.all()` like that:

```
return (
    Promise.all(items.map((item) => {
        <div>{item.name}</div>
        // function that returns a promise
        // the endpoint requires the item's id
        this.apiCall(item.id).then((returnedValue) => {
            return <div>{returnedValue}</div>
        });
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform an async operation in the render method, but you could encapsulate the Api call in a child component (which you would render instead), then you could handle the call inside the child component logic, something along these lines:

```
constructor(props) {
  apiCall(props.id).then((value) => { this.setState({value}) });

  this.state = {
      value: ''
  }
}

render() {
    return (<div>{this.state.value}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your JSX synchronously from the render method, so you are better of getting your API data in `componentDidMount` instead and setting it in the component state when the requests are done.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { items: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    const items = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "test"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "test2"
      }
    ];

    Promise.all(
      items.map(item =>
        this.apiCall(item.id).then(returnedValue => {
          item.returnedValue = returnedValue;
          return item;
        })
      )
    ).then(items => {
      this.setState({ items });
    });
  }

  apiCall = id => {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 1000)
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
            <div>{item.returnedValue}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```